# json returning string instead of object

Tags: php, javascript, json

i have

```
 $age = implode(',', $wage);   // which is object return:  [1,4],[7,11],[15,11]
  $ww = json_encode($age);
```

and then i retrieve it here

```
    var age = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($ww); ?>);
```

so if i make

```
   alert(typeof(<?php echo $age; ?>))   // object
   alert(typeof(age))                   //string
```

in my case JSON.parse retuned as string.

how can i let json return as object?

EDIT:

```
 var age = JSON.parse(<?php echo $ww; ?>); // didnt work , its something syntax error
```

Comment: `$ww=json_encode($age)` then you echo `json_encode($ww);` so really `var age=JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode(json_encode($age)); ?>` Is this what you really want to be doing?

Comment: why are you using json_encode twice? In the second time you are basically running json_encode on a string, which doesn't make sense, since json_encode runs on arrays\objects and turns them into strings

Comment: i edited my post as u told me @Matanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var age = [<?php echo $age; ?>];
```

Answer (score 2):

`implode` returns a string, so it is only natural that `json_encode` encodes it as such. It does not recognize already JSON-like data passed as a string.

If you want to get an object, you have to pass an associative array to `json_encode`:

```
$foo = array(
    1 => 4,
    7 => 11,
    15 => 11
);

echo json_encode($foo); // {1:4,7:11,15:11}
```

With so little info about what `$wage` looks like before it's imploded, it's hard to tell exactly what you want to get. How is that structure (`[1,4],[7,11],[15,11]`) an object? Is the first element of each tuple a key? That's what I assumed with my example, but it might be off.

Comment: but why type of $age is object and type of age is string in my code

Comment: @peter, you have to look at the code this generates. You first example does `typeof([1,4],[7,11],[15,11])`, and `typeof` on an array returns `object` (put simply, `typeof` returns the type of the last comma-separated value it receives as an argument). In your second case, you get `typeof("[1,4],[7,11],[15,11]")`, which definitely is a `string` literal (notice the quotes).

Comment: i didnt make `typeof("[1,4],[7,11],[15,11]")` with double quotes

Comment: @peter, you did not exactly do it, but you did `var age = JSON.parse("\"[1,4],[7,11],[15,11]\"");` and then `typeof(age)`. (Look at how you call `json_encode` twice, once on `$wage` to get `$age` and then again on `$age` to put it in your Javascript.)

Comment: so how to fix this then? to remove those double quotes .thx for the help

Comment: Don't call `json_encode` twice. Just `echo $ww` instead of `echo json_encode($ww)`. Though this will still probably not give you what you expect as it will return `[15,11]` only. This is the part where you need to clarify what you want, and in which for you want it. Why don't you edit your question to include exactly the JSON string you would like to get?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20819/discussion-between-zneak-and-peter)

Answer (score 1):

a. You get a syntax error because you need to enclose the string within quotes, like so:

`var age = JSON.parse("<?php echo $ww; ?>");`

b. Moreover, you *don't need* `JSON.parse`. You can simply echo the php var after it was already json_encoded in the server side:

`var age = <?php echo $ww; ?>;`

JSON.parse is there to convert a *JavaScript* string to an object. In the case of PHP string, once it is built as JSON, echoing it in the right place is equivalent to coding it yourself.

Comment: first i dont see where i have writed double quotes as u mentioned

Comment: a. You didn't. You should have. b. As I said, this is redundant

Comment: b variable age is also string without json parse

Comment: removed json parse but it same , its string for variable age

Comment: go to `view source` in the browser please and paste it here so I can see how it is parsed

Comment: here it looks in sourse code `var age = "[1,4],[7,11],[15,11]";`

Comment: those quotes are in console , its not me who made them , how u think they will removed?